# Writing my own consumer thread -- what am I not seeing?

Tags: java, concurrency

So, I have a BlockingQueue which I'm filling up with data (from many threads). I want to aggregate this data into buckets of, say 1000, then pass them off to somewhere else. So I have written a thread class which polls the end of the queue, and when it has enough elements, it sends off the aggregated data.

I expected to find something in java.util.concurrent to help more with this. The only way I can see to do this through java.util.concurrent would be to have every insertion to the queue add a runnable to task which would then add to an aggregating set, but this seems really inefficient to me.

With the threads polling the queue strategy, say I have 5 threads, each thread can aggregate in local memory (order is not really important), and then pass off. The queue and the destination are the only touch points for contention -- 1 thread can poll off a blocking queue at a time. The destination is probably not ever going to be in contention.

With the task-based approach, using an Executor, all the threads will be sharing an aggregation point, so that will be constantly in contention, not to mention synchronized/concurrent variations of collections are slower.

Seems obvious to just have a few threads always polling the BlockingQueue. The downside is now I need to write all their starts, stops, I'll need to handle the case that a thread dies, etc. This all seems like boilerplate I'd expect to find in java.util.concurrent or maybe an apache library.

Am I really that far off the reservation? A class to just always have x threads running and restart them if they fail? Is there another obvious (performant) approach that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: Neither the problem you face nor your desired solution are very clear. Perhaps some pseudo code would clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
public class Consumer<DATA> {

    private List<DATA> dataList = new ArrayList<DATA>();

    private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public synchronized void consume(DATA data) {

        dataList.add(data);

        if(dataList.size() >= 1000) {

            threadPool.submit(new ConsumerWorker(data));
        }
    }

}
```

We are essentially accumulating data in producer's thread context till it hits the desired limit. Then we are submitting the batch of data to a thread pool which will queue or execute ConsumerWorker(s) based on their availability. You can tune behavior of the thread pool too. For example using newCachedThreadPool() will remove inactive threads.

Comment: the OP states in the first sentence that there are many producers, so this doesn't work.

Comment: Yup, my fault.

I've modified the code. Consumer method is now synchronized. Was probably focused on reducing boilerplate code that the question mentioned.

Comment: This does seem cleaner than what I'm doing. At the least it seems more readable and maintainable which is at least half the battle. The synchronized block is also significantly faster than adding to a blockingQueue.

Comment: small update -- synchronized block is faster, but maybe not "significantly" ~20%.

Comment: Refactoring with this in mind lead me to producing significantly simpler code than I had. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if i were to implement this, i would simply have one thread which calls `take()` (not poll) on the blocking queue until it gets a full batch and then hands this batch off to your processing code.  if the batch handling logic is potentially long, this would probably be a separate worker thread pool.  your post is long and talks about submitting runnables with every item(?), various alleged points of contention, and other things which i didn't completely follow.  not sure why it needs to be more any more complex than what i just described.  (this would utilize BlockingQueue and Executors from java.util.concurrent and would not require any direct Thread management).

Comment: I agree. Seems pretty simple but the question rambled all over so I can't be sure.

Comment: Sorry the question was so unclear. How would you use an Executor to have a thread continually call take() to fill a batch?

Comment: @JohnHinnegan - you would just submit a Runnable to the executor which loops and calls `take()` until it fills up a batch, then dispatches it.

Comment: @jtahlborn right, so that's basically what I was building and that lead me to code that seemed unnecessarily complex. You need failsafe in case the thread dies. If you want more consumers, you need more threads and more jobs submitted (coupling). Since I always want consumers right from the get-go, I had to hook this into the program's initialization, etc. It was just a lot of boilerplate and I was looking for a simpler solution.